# the answer only keeps saying the first one

Tags: python, random

Every time I put in a number, it only prints the first input everytime instead of it being random. This is the code I used:

```
import random 
import sys 

answer = True 
while answer:
  question = input("Roll the di to get your fortune: ")

  answers = random.randint(1,6) 

  if question == "":
    sys.exit()

  elif answer == 1: 
    print("You will get a new friend. ")

  elif answer == 2:
    print("You will go to disneyland. ")

  elif answer == 3: 
    print("You will receive kindess.. ")

  elif answer == 4:
    print("Your will get a dog. ")

  elif answer == 5:
    print("You will suffer. ")

  elif answer == 6:
    print("You will have bad luck. ")






roll()
```

I really need help, I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Note that you have two variables with similar names: `answer` and `answers`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here where you're assigning to `answers` instead of `answer`:

```
  answers = random.randint(1,6)
```

The `True` value you assigned to `answer` is the only one it will ever have; `True` is considered equal to `1` which is why you only ever get the first answer.

Using `answer` as your loop condition as well as for the die roll is a little confusing -- once you fix the typo above, it kind of works because all of the die rolls are "truthy", but it would work just as well (and be less prone to causing mistakes like this one) to use `while True` for the loop rather than using a variable whose value can never be false.  Note that if you hadn't set `answer = True` at the start of your script, you would have spotted the `answers` typo immediately because checking `answer == 1` would have raised a `NameError`.  In general, the fewer variables you have to keep track of, and the less time you have to keep track of them for, the fewer chances there are for something to go wrong!

You don't need the `question` variable either since you immediately break the loop if it's empty and don't do anything else with it -- and for that matter you don't really need to keep track of `answer` and have a bunch of `if` statements based on it, since all you're really doing is picking one out of six possibilities -- there's a function called `random.choice` that makes that easy!

```
import random

while True:
    if not input("Roll the die to get your fortune: "):
        break
    print(random.choice([
        "You will get a new friend. ",
        "You will go to disneyland. ",
        "You will receive kindess.. ",
        "Your will get a dog. ",
        "You will suffer. ",
        "You will have bad luck. ",
    ]))
```

```
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will suffer.
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will receive kindess..
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will suffer.
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will receive kindess..
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
Your will get a dog.
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will have bad luck.
Roll the die to get your fortune: ok
You will go to disneyland.
Roll the die to get your fortune:
```

Comment: It will be better if you can also explain how your code is working.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you could make your code easier to work with if you replace your elifs with a dictionary of responses:

```
import random 
import sys 

responses = {
    1: "You will get a new friend. ",
    2: "You will go to disneyland. ",
    3: "You will receive kindess.. ",
    4: "Your will get a dog. ",
    5: "You will suffer. ",
    6: "You will have bad luck. "
}

answer = True 
while answer:
    question = input("Roll the di to get your fortune: ")

    answer = random.randint(1,6) 

    if question == "":
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print(responses[answer])


roll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines in your code :

```
  elif answer == 1: 
    print("You will get a new friend. ")

  elif answer == 2:
    print("You will go to disneyland. ")

  elif answer == 3: 
    print("You will receive kindess.. ")

  elif answer == 4:
    print("Your will get a dog. ")

  elif answer == 5:
    print("You will suffer. ")

  elif answer == 6:
    print("You will have bad luck. ")
```

to these:

```
  elif answers == 1: 
    print("You will get a new friend. ")

  elif answers == 2:
    print("You will go to disneyland. ")

  elif answers == 3: 
    print("You will receive kindess.. ")

  elif answers == 4:
    print("Your will get a dog. ")

  elif answers == 5:
    print("You will suffer. ")

  elif answers == 6:
    print("You will have bad luck. ")
```

Where you went **wrong**: You were using `answer` variable defined as `True` in your conditions. In Python, `True` has a value of `1` this is why it was always running the condition `"You will get a new friend. "`. Also, you were storing the random dice digits in `answers` variable. Hope you understood!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra s when you roll the die on answers.
It should be:

```
answer = random.randint(1,6)
```

Comment: `answer` is also an odd name to use - as it's not an answer per se... would probably be clearer if it was called `dice_roll`/`roll` or something

Comment: `answer` is set to `True`. He/She needs to change `answer` to `answers` in conditions.